# Blazor app on Azure is giving error You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I am new to Azure and trying to learn it. Today I created a Blazor app (out of the box app which creates 3 components - Index, Counter and Weather). After creating this app I deployed to Azure web app. After that I tried to browse the app, using the url mentioned on the App Service Overview page. The url is **https://contactmanagerjain.azurewebsites.net**. But when I browse to that page I get the error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page". What setting I might be missing. This is my first day on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying it wrong and because of which no files were going to the server. After I fixed the issue, I was able to publish it and got it working.